# .NET 4 MemoryCache with CacheMemoryLimiteMegabytes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, caching

I never tried using MemoryCache and I'm trying to understand it. I am experimenting on how it will Trim/Remove cache entries in the cache when the cachememorylimitmegabytes is exceeded. Testing it with 1 mega

```
        //Initialization...
        var cacheSettings = new NameValueCollection(3);
        cacheSettings.Add("cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", Convert.ToString(1));
        cacheSettings.Add("pollingInterval", Convert.ToString("00:00:01"));
        cacheSettings.Add("physicalMemoryLimitPercentage", Convert.ToString(1));
        cache = new MemoryCache("test", cacheSettings);
        CreateExistingCacheTest();



    private void CreateExistingCacheTest()
    {
        int z = 0;
        while (z < 10)
        {
            var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
            var i = 0;
            while (i < 100000)
            {
                hashSet.Add(Guid.NewGuid()
                                .ToString());
                i++;
            }
            cache.Add(new CacheItem(z.ToString(), hashSet), new CacheItemPolicy());
            z++;
    }
```

And a button that just adds a new cache item

```
    private HashSet<string> CreateDummyValues()
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
        var i = 0;
        while (i < 1000000)
        {
            hashSet.Add(Guid.NewGuid()
                            .ToString());
            i++;
        }
        return hashSet;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender,
                                    RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dummyValues = CreateDummyValues();
        var cacheItem = new CacheItem(keystring.Text, dummyValues);
        cache.Add(cacheItem, new CacheItemPolicy());
        Debug.WriteLine(cache.GetCount());
    }
```

**Question:**
Why is setting cacheMemoryLimit doesn't look like it is obeying how it should evict cache entries? It doesn't seem to evict the previous CacheEntries given that it don't have any CacheItemPolicy on how it will be evicted. I am expecting it to drop the previous cache entries once I press the button because I am trying to add a cache item that has a value of more than 1 mb.

Comment: `Convert.ToString("00:00:01")` ... Why are you converting a string in to a string? Also for the other options, why not just pass in `"1"`?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a prototype. Was mixing if it there is a difference putting 00:00:01 and 1 so I tried different values with different elements. I figured "00:00:01" is equal to "1" being passed through when it is parsed internally by the MemoryCache.